# salesforce - Getting error incorrect signature: void valueof(pse_timecard_header_c) from the type decimal

Tags: apex, trigger, community, salesforce1-app

I was trying to create a separate record in a custom object having hours - for time submitted on every day in the standard timecard object of financial force. Please see the code below

Also - please excuse silly mistake as i am a beginner and learning.

Trigger -

```
trigger TimecardOutput1 on pse__Timecard_Header__c (after insert) {
TimecardOutput1.afterInsert(Trigger.New);
    }
```

```
Class - 
public with sharing class TimecardOutput1 
{
    public static void afterInsert(pse__Timecard_Header__c[] timeCard)
    { 
        List<pse__Timecard_Header__c> hoursEntered = new List<pse__Timecard_Header__c>();
        hoursEntered=  [select pse__Monday_Hours__c, 
                        pse__Tuesday_Hours__c, 
                        pse__Wednesday_Hours__c, 
                        pse__Thursday_Hours__c,
                        pse__Friday_Hours__c,
                        pse__Saturday_Hours__c,
                        pse__Sunday_Hours__c   
                        from pse__Timecard_Header__c];
         integer i = hoursEntered.size();

        List<Timecard_integration__c> timeCardIntegration = new List<Timecard_integration__c>();
        for (pse__Timecard_Header__c tc : timeCard)
        {            
               for (Integer j = 0; j<=i;j++)
                timeCardIntegration.add(new Timecard_integration__c (Name = tc.Id, hours__c= decimal.valueOf(hoursEntered.get(j)), CurrencyIsoCode= tc.CurrencyIsoCode ));
            insert timeCardIntegration;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here:

```
timeCardIntegration.add(
  new Timecard_integration__c (
    Name = tc.Id, 
    hours__c= decimal.valueOf(hoursEntered.get(j)), 
    CurrencyIsoCode= tc.CurrencyIsoCode ));
```

`hoursEntered.get(j)` is a record, but Decimal.valueOf can only work on certain data types, such as a String or an Integer. You need to specify which value you're trying to get from the `pse__Timecard_Head__c` record you're trying to use. Further, the fields you're querying are likely already Decimal types and don't need to use `Decimal.valueOf` at all. It's not clear, however, what you're trying to do, so you'll need to fix this on your own.

---

Also, while we're on the subject of simple mistakes:

```
    for (pse__Timecard_Header__c tc : timeCard)
    {            
        ...
        insert timeCardIntegration;
    }
```

Will result in errors if more than one pse_Timecard_Header__c is passed in to your method. Make sure you perform DML outside of all loops:

```
    for (pse__Timecard_Header__c tc : timeCard)
    {            
        ...
    }
    insert timeCardIntegration;
```

---

Also, generally speaking, you should always use `{}` around an optional block (e.g. for loop, if branch, etc), even if there is only one statement. This helps avoid coding bugs.

```
// Do not forget the curly brackets.
for (Integer j = 0; j<=i;j++)
    timeCardIntegration.add(new Timecard_integration__c (Name = tc.Id, hours__c= decimal.valueOf(hoursEntered.get(j)), CurrencyIsoCode= tc.CurrencyIsoCode ));


// This is the proper way to do this:

for (Integer j = 0; j<=i;j++) {
    timeCardIntegration.add(new Timecard_integration__c (Name = tc.Id, hours__c= decimal.valueOf(hoursEntered.get(j)), CurrencyIsoCode= tc.CurrencyIsoCode ));
}
```

---

As a simple matter of performance, you should avoid using List.get:

```
hoursEntered.get(j)
```

And instead use the square-bracket array notation:

```
hoursEntered[i]
```

This is better for performance and generally easier to read.

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation. !! As you see in my code, currently as per standard Financial force the time are entered weekly. So i am trying to capture the time entered on all those 7 days in my SOQL query 
and then I was trying to create a separate record for each day in a custom object to process it to downstream.